# Does anybody knows how this (google help) is called

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows

Does anybody knows how this (google help) is called
for example when you type "f" there writes: facebook, fandago, fox news, etc

Comment: Should this be in the "English Grammar & Usage" section of SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already answered, it's called Google Autocomplete, and you can read a LOT more about it [on this link](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106230): Hope it helps... ;)

Answer (score 1):

It has different words, but they all mean the same:

- **Bootstrap** calls it [Typeahed](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)
- **jQuery UI** calls it [AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
- **Yahoo** calls it [AutoComplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/) as well

and plenty examples out there, but the majority calls it **auto complete**.

Answer (score 1):

[Autocomplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete), or some variation of that. As for practical use on your website, form completion or an internal search engine are the predominant uses. [Here is a jQuery autocomplete demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).